# How to get value from request object of http cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying firebase cloud function. I have 1 question any suggestion while greatly appreciate.

I have create http function like below

```
export const getWelcomeName = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>{

})
```

I have created 1 android app which will call http function with `hashmap` object contain name of person.

```
private void getName() {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("name", getIntent().getExtras().getString("username"));

        FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
                .getHttpsCallable("getWelcomeName")
                .call(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {
                        snackbar.dismiss();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
```

How can I return response with appended welcome string using http function
like "Welcome Jake"?

Comment: I looks like you haven't consulted the documentation.  If you're trying to invoke a callable function, you need to declare it as a callable in cloud functions (not an https function as you're showing).  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: i got your point but still cant get solution. between thank you

Comment: getting null in data